# Prime number $p$ such that $p+1$ has all given prime numbers as prime factor.

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

For given finite prime numbers set $P$,
does there exist some prime number $p$ such that
for any $\ell\in P$, $\ell\mid (p+1)$?

For example, if $P=\{2,3,7\}$, then we can take $p=41$.
In this case, $(\prod_{\ell\in P}\ell)-1$ is already prime number, so it's simple.

Even if this is not the case, e.g. $P=\{5,7\}$, we can take $p=f\cdot (\prod_{\ell\in P}\ell)-1$ where $f=4, p=139$.

I consider there exists counterexample, but giving the example is difficult since for

$p=826791736418446924644415105270960270928927659729776400179861442336062222833458285859,$

$(p+1)$ has all under $200$ primes as prime factor.

Especially, I want to know the case $P_{\le B}:=\{\ell~|~\ell \le B,~ \ell~ {\rm is  ~prime }\}$ where $B$ is some integer.

Please help me.

Comment: Yes: Let $N$ be the product of the primes in your set. By Dirichlet’s theorem (in fact, one of the cases that be proved without L-functions), there is a prime $p$ congruent to $-1$ modulo $N$.

Comment: This follows immediately from [Dirichlet's theorem on infinitely many primes on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions). More precisely, if $\gcd(a,n)=1$ there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p\equiv a\pmod{n}$. Here $a=-1$, and $n$ is that product of primes $\ell$.